# How to achieve EventBroadcast by using presence channel in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, websocket, broadcast, pusher, laravel-broadcast

I am very new to the laravel Event Broadcasting Concept ,i have some requirement without refreshing page i need to update the data in Angular site.i made a presence channel by using pusher.i called my broadcast in my queue class once it's triggered i got an API message from the Pusher Debugger console with what data it's triggered until this part fine.First of all i want to know weather server side implementation code and logic was correct if wrong means can you help to fix ?

```
broadcast(new Message('57585');
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Config;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config as FacadesConfig;

class Message implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message= $message;
    
    }




    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('test'.$this->message);
    }

   


}
```

`channels.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('test.{message}', function ($user, $message) {
        return true;
});
```

I am getting in Pusher console like my main doubt is weather this implementation is correct or not.if possible can you give some brief about concept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can able to see some problems with this code channel name is correctly `concatinated with dot` in `channels.php` but not where your'e returning presence channel so modify your code like in Event Class(Message.php)

```
public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('test.'.$this->message); 
                        or
        return new PresenceChannel('test'.'.'.$this->message);
    }
```

And after this your'e using presence channel so you must **authorize** the user and return the user details if the user is valid otherwise null,simply can't able to return true or false [According to laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#presence-channels).

```
Broadcast::channel('test.{message}', function ($user, $message) {
        $user_valid = //write your authorization logic which will return boolean
        if($user_valid){
            return $user ; //if you don't want entire user object we can pass specific variables inside array
         }
});
```

For code cleaner you can write Authorization logic inside Channel Class or you can create in User model as per your wish.For more info [Check docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting)

Hope This will work ..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authenticated when you use presence channel because technically Presence channel is using private channel [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#presence-channels)

```
Broadcast::channel('test.{message}', function ($user, $message) {
    if (auth()->check()){
        return $user;
     } 
});
```

And you have a bit of mistake in you broadcastOn method, it should be:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('test.'.$this->message);
}
```

I have created a free websocket server that uses pusher protocol v7 you might be interested. https://soket.uk